# Button collapses/expands accordions only on second click Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

I have this button that collapses/expands all accordions on the page when clicked. The Problem is when I first load the page it will only starting collapsing/expanding everything after I click a ***second*** time on the button, then it works on every click.

**Button HTML:**

```
<Button id="collapseAll" class="btn btn-secondary">Collapse/Expand</Button>
```

**Button JS:**

```
$("#collapseAll").click( function() {
        if(!$('.accordion-header').hasClass("active")){
            $('.accordion-header').removeClass("active").addClass("active");

        } else {
            $('.accordion-header').addClass("active").removeClass("active");
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#collapseAll").click( function() {
            if(!$('.accordion-header').hasClass("active")){
                $('.accordion-header').removeClass("active").addClass("active");

            } else {
                $('.accordion-header').addClass("active").removeClass("active");
            }
        });

});
```

Comment: sadly still only starts working on second click

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with your css code.

you can add the following css and it should work fine..

```
.accordion-header{
      display:none;
}

.accordion-header.active{
     display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Validate if it matches your requirement. Also you can refer the link http://accordion-cd.blogspot.com/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#accordion").accordion({
      collapsible:true,
  });
var icons = $( "#accordion" ).accordion( "option", "icons" );
$('.open').click(function () {
$('.ui-accordion-header').removeClass('ui-corner-all').addClass('ui-accordion-header-active ui-state-active ui-corner-top').attr({
    'aria-selected': 'true',
        'tabindex': '0'
      });
$(this).attr("disabled","disabled");
$('.close').removeAttr("disabled");
});    
});
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).